# The citation autocomplete preview disappears

Tags: texstudio

I love the reference (\cite} autocomplete feature in Texstudio. I use it all the time. 
I also love the fact that it has a little preview which shows the details on each reference.

But, recently, the little preview window that shows the details of the references (the author, date, title etc) start to disappear immediately. It used to give me time to check the right reference by reading the titles.

Look at the following video to see the little preview disappearing immediately.

http://take.ms/2zDXr

Have anyone experienced the same problem?
(I have tried to delete the user profile, and tested different versions of  Texstudio, with no avail).

Comment: I learned that it is a bug in the latter versions of QT.

Answer (score 1):

This is a similar disappearing tooltip/preview thread that tinkering around with somehow worked for me: [Texstudio tooltip help on mouseover only displaying for about 1 second](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/500114/texstudio-tooltip-help-on-mouseover-only-displaying-for-about-1-second)