# Texstudio tooltip help on mouseover only displaying for about 1 second

Tags: texstudio, tooltips

In texstudio, if I mouse over a command e.g. /caption, a tooltip will appear that describes the command. This option is toggled on and off via configure -> adv. options -> special options -> Show help as tooltip on text in editor.

I would like to use this feature as I am new to Latex. However, when I mouse over, the tooltip displays for maybe 1 second and then disappears. Any ideas on how to make this duration longer or permanent?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

fellow newbie who is similarly frustrated here. Literally started yesterday but I figured out if you uncheck the "show preview as tooltip on formulas in editor" under the "preview" tab of configure it let the tooltips I wanted to see stick around. I don't know what specific tooltips you have but hope this helps.

Comment: Oh gosh, that's pretty unintuitive. Thanks for finding that out! It seems to work, so I'll be sure to accept this barring any more thorough answers forthcoming in the next several hours or so.